# How AR model parameters are estimated?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I know that AR(p) is defined like this: 
$$
y_{t} = c + \phi_{1}y_{t-1} + \phi_{2}y_{t-2} + \dots + \phi_{p}y_{t-p} + \varepsilon_{t},
$$

From what I understood, this means $y_{t}$ value is predicted using the $p$ past values of the time series, and each value is given a weight (coefficient) $ \phi_{p}$, and this  weight varies according how much this $y_{t-p}$ is correlated with $y_{t}$.

Using statsmodel library, after fitting a AR(4) model, and printing `model.summary()` I got:

[image]

Are AR.1, AR.2 ... values the same as $\phi$, if so how are they computed? And what are the meaning of Real, Imaginary, Modulus, Frequency?

[image]

And after plotting the PACF of my time series, it doesn't seem to match AR values I got in the summary (ex: AR.2 , it is negatively correlated in the graph meanwhile the $\phi$ value is positive).

Answer (score 1):

When you estimate an AR(p) model in Statsmodels and print the summary, there are three tables printed.

(**Note**: you should use `sm.tsa.AutoReg` and not `sm.tsa.AR`. `sm.tsa.AutoReg` is new in v0.11 but it is now the recommended way to fit AR(p) models)

For example:

[image: statsmodels AR(p) results summary]

The three tables are:

1. The first table describes the dataset, and gives summary information like the log likelihood and information criteria.
2. The second table gives the parameters of the model, including the intercept `c` and the autoregressive parameters `phi_1` ... `phi_2`. The autoregressive parameters are named `<variable>.L1` ... `<variable>.Lp`, where `<variable>` is the variable name if you passed a Pandas Series or it is `y` if you passed e.g. a numpy array.
3. The third table gives the roots of the autoregressive lag polynomial.

In your question, the table that you showed was the third table, showing the roots of the lag polynomial. What it seems like you were looking for were the autoregressive coefficients, and these are given in the second table of the summary output (which you did not include in your question).